# How to change templates after clicking Button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I would like to change view of button after button is clicked.
For example, I have two templates `beforeClicking` and `afterClicking`:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Name="beforeClicking">
                <Border Name="border" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Border>                    
            </ControlTemplate>
            <!--It is not permitted, but that is pseudocode(what I want)
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Name="afterClicking">
                <Border Name="border" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="10" BorderBrush="Black">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Border>                    
            </ControlTemplate>
            -->
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

What I want is  when button is not clicked, then a template `beforeClicking` should be permanently used and nothing(template or view) should not be altered.
 However, if user clicks, then button should use 
a template `afterClicking` permanently and the view of button should not be altered.

That is at the first click the button uses template `afterClicking`. At the second click the button uses template `beforeClicking`. At the third click the button uses template `afterClicking`. At the fourth click the button uses template `afterClicking`. And so on.

I would like to get such behavior just by XAML since MVVM approach is used.

**How to achieve such a behavior?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle a click using an EventTrigger.  In an event trigger you provide a Storyboard, but in a Storyboard you can't change the Template.

You could do this in an attached property, but looking at your example, you don't need to, and more typically, you'd affect individual properties:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Name="border" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="Black">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness">
                            <DiscreteThicknessKeyFrame Value="10" KeyTime="0" />
                        </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

==After discussion: ToggleButton version:==

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Border Name="border" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="Black">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="10" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ToggleButton>Hello World</ToggleButton>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It works okay, however if I click the second time, then Button template is not returned to initial state. Please, see my updated answer.

Comment: Oh sorry, misunderstood; didnt realise you wanted a "toggle", thought you wanted it to stick.  In which case you are actually better off using a ToggleButton?  Then you can bind your BorderThickness to a trigger on the IsChecked property.

Comment: please, write your answer about toggle button and I will accept it.

Comment: OK, updated main answer.  Paste that straight into a Window.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would use `System.Windows.Interactivity.Behavior` rather than `EventTriggers`, unfortunately `EventTriggers` are the only way for you to associate in xaml event with operation, the only problem is that `EventTriggers` only work with `TriggerAction` objects and you can't create your `TriggerAction`. This because it is an abstract class which abstract methods are internal and not overridable from outside PresentationFramework library.
Here is an example of how prepare your Behavior class:

```
public class ChangeTemplateBehavior : System.Windows.Interactivity.Behavior<Button>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ControlTemplate1Property = DependencyProperty.Register("ControlTemplate1", typeof(ControlTemplate), typeof(ChangeTemplateBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(default(ControlTemplate)));

    public ControlTemplate ControlTemplate1
    {
        get
        {
            return (ControlTemplate)GetValue(ControlTemplate1Property);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ControlTemplate1Property, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ControlTemplate2Property = DependencyProperty.Register("ControlTemplate2", typeof(ControlTemplate), typeof(ChangeTemplateBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(default(ControlTemplate)));

    public ControlTemplate ControlTemplate2
    {
        get
        {
            return (ControlTemplate)GetValue(ControlTemplate2Property);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ControlTemplate2Property, value);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        this.AssociatedObject.Click += AssociatedObject_Click;
    }

    void AssociatedObject_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.AssociatedObject.Template == this.ControlTemplate2)
        {
            this.AssociatedObject.Template = this.ControlTemplate1;
        }
        else
        {
            this.AssociatedObject.Template = this.ControlTemplate2;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is an example of how to write your xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="StackoverflowHelpWPF5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:[YOURLOCALNAMESPACEHERE]"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>

        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="beforeClicking">
            <Border Name="border" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                <ContentPresenter/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="afterClicking">
            <Border Name="border" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="10" BorderBrush="Black">
                <ContentPresenter/>
            </Border>                    
        </ControlTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>

    ...

    <Button  Template="{StaticResource beforeClicking}" >
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <local:ChangeTemplateBehavior ControlTemplate1="{StaticResource afterClicking}" ControlTemplate2="{StaticResource beforeClicking}"></local:ChangeTemplateBehavior>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Button>
```

Comment: please write description of staticResources. Just the simplest, but work example)

Comment: Just added, have a look at them ;)

Comment: Thanks:). It works okay, however if I click the second time, then Button template is not returned to initial state.